# why TDs display within a TR displays in the same line?

Tags: css, html-table

TD is a block element,

but displays like inline,say,several TDs within a TR display in the same line,

why?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's not a bad question.

Comment: I agree. Too many people here vote down legitimate questions for insufficient reasons.

Comment: I downvoted for lack of clarity. In particular, what exactly is meant by "displays like inline"? Edit for clarity and I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 14):

TD's are actually not technically "block" elements.  Have a look at the [CSS display property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp).  Cells are technically of type "table-cell" and they are a special case.

There is also another type of display called "inline-block" which can be useful.

Comment: upvoted, since it's almost exactly what I answered with, though I was a few seconds slower =) ...deleting

Comment: It's similar, but not exactly the same.  There are special layout considerations for tables that don't apply to explicit inline-block elements, although I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are for tabular data.

Comment: Is there a more consistent way to explain that?

Comment: Shore, you might as well ask why links are clickable. It's inherent to their existence - it's the behavior they were created to display.

Answer (score 1):

Because, that's how tables work.

Comment: One of the rare occasions "just because" is an adequate response :)

Answer (score 0):

TR = table row. How else would you want it to behave?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `<td>` to display as a "block," simply add another `<tr>` below the current `<tr>`.  This will effectively make the `<td>` act like a block-level element.

Let's say you have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table cell A</td>
        <td>Table cell B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And you want "Table cell B" to act like a "block." You could do this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table cell A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table cell B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This moves Table cell B below Table cell A.